# ResourceExhaustedError: {{function_node __wrapped__Mul_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} failed to allocate memory [Op:Mul]

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am trying to read and load image segmentation dataset using colab. i am using colab gpu runtime. here is the code.

```
class Dataset():
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        root_path: str,
        mode: str
    ):
        if mode == "TRAIN":
            self.PATH = os.path.join(root_path, "Train")
        elif mode == "TEST":
            self.PATH = os.path.join(root_path, "Test")
        
        self.images = os.listdir(self.PATH + "/images")
        self.masks = os.listdir(self.PATH + "/masks")
    
    def load_data(self):
        
        images = []
        masks = []
        
        for index in range(len(self.images)):            
            image = tf.io.read_file(os.path.join(self.PATH, "images", self.images[index]))
            image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
            image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
            
            mask = tf.io.read_file(os.path.join(self.PATH, "masks", self.images[index]))
            mask = tf.image.decode_jpeg(mask, channels=3)
            mask = tf.math.reduce_max(mask, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

            height, width = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
            height -=  height % 16
            width -= width % 16
            
            image = tf.image.resize(image, (height, width), method="nearest")
            mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (height, width), method="nearest")

            images.append(image)
            masks.append(mask)
    
        return tf.stack(images, axis=0), tf.stack(masks, axis=0)
```

```
train_dataset = Dataset(root_path=PATH, mode="TRAIN")
train_images, train_masks = train_dataset.load_data()

test_dataset = Dataset(root_path=PATH, mode="TEST")
test_images, test_masks = test_dataset.load_data()
```

here is the error i got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-83bcb83ccdb2> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 train_dataset = Dataset(root_path=PATH, mode="TRAIN")
----> 2 train_images, train_masks = train_dataset.load_data()
      3 
      4 test_dataset = Dataset(root_path=PATH, mode="TEST")
      5 test_images, test_masks = test_dataset.load_data()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7260 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7261   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7262   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7263 
   7264 

ResourceExhaustedError: {{function_node __wrapped__Mul_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} failed to allocate memory [Op:Mul]
```

i am trying to read and load the image segmentation dataset using tensorflow. dataset details here ---> https://data.lib.vt.edu/articles/dataset/Concrete_Crack_Conglomerate_Dataset/16625056

Comment: Did you try to reduce the size of batch? (e.g. 32 -> 16)

Comment: no didn't define the batch size how to do that?